# PIC Microstick vs Pickit

Tags: pic, pickit

I am starting new in using PIC MCUs and am slightly confused by these two available options.

Pickit is a programmer/debugger, that's what they say. Now, there is this something called Microstick which is a ready-made development board with an inbuilt programmer/debugger. Microstick seems to me to be like an Arduino for PICs. Furthermore, Microstick is almost half the price of Pickit.

Now, the question is that why would one buy Pickit if Microstick can already do what Pickit can? I mean Pickit is just a programmer while Microstick seems to me to be not only a programmer but also a quick-start development board.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with either product, but I don't think you can use a Microstick to program anything except the one chip that is on the stick.  The PicKit, ICDs, and RealIce are intended to work with *your* target hardware.  Also, I sortof remember that the Arduino-compatible offering is called something like "ChipKit".

Comment: @OlinLathrop: Thanks a lot. You have actually partially answered my question. Microstick can program only a limited MCUs. MCUs are not soldered into the board and you can replace them but I think only a limited range of MCUs can be programmed. And thanks for informing me about the Arduino-compatible offering for PICs.

Comment: Software can also be debugged, as with the PICkit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are, at the moment, 4 different flavors of Microstick boards:

- [Microstick for 3V PIC24F K-series](http://www.microchip.com/DevelopmentTools/ProductDetails.aspx?PartNO=DM240013-1). Supported parts: PIC24F16KL402, PIC24F16KA102, PIC24F08KL302, PIC24F08KL402, PIC24F08KA102, PIC24F16KA302, PIC24F32KA302
- [Microstick for 5V PIC24F    K-Series](http://www.microchip.com/DevelopmentTools/ProductDetails.aspx?PartNO=DM240013-2). Supported parts: PIC24FV16KM202, PIC24FV08KM202, PIC24FV16KM102, PIC24FV08KM102, PIC24FV32KA302, PIC24FV16KA302
- [Microstick for dsPIC33F and PIC24H Development Board](http://www.microchip.com/DevelopmentTools/ProductDetails.aspx?PartNO=DM330013). Supported parts: dsPIC33FJ64MC802, dsPIC33FJ128MC802, PIC24HJ64GP502, PIC24HJ128GP502
- [Microstick II](http://www.microchip.com/DevelopmentTools/ProductDetails.aspx?PartNO=DM330013-2). Supported parts: all 3.3V PIC24FJ, PIC24E, PIC24H, dsPIC33, and PIC32 28-pin SPDIP packaged devices

The Microstick boards are development boards which also have an integrated programmer/debugger that only works with the microcontrollers that they support. If you go this way, I suggest you buy the Microstick II dev board (@ $35) as it supports the most microcontrollers. And no, the Microstick boards have nothing in common with the Arduino boards.

The [PICkit 3 programmer/debugger](http://www.microchip.com/Developmenttools/ProductDetails.aspx?PartNO=PG164130) **supports all the available Microchip microcontrollers to date**. And it's under $50. A great investment if you're planning on working with different families of PIC microcontrollers. Note also that the Microstick boards don't support any of the 8-bit PICs.

Comment: wow! thanx for a complete answer. This clears up my question.